# lost right-click open with java - jar file

Tags: java

How do I setup Unity to right-click-open a java file?  I have tried to "set the default action" but the action is not listed and I cannot add an action from the menus.  When I right-click-properties then click the "open with" tab, the "add" button is greyed out.

I write alot of java software. I need the ability to open it from the Desktop.

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open /usr/share/applications and look for a file named "OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime".
If it doesn't exists create a file named /usr/share/applications/openjdk-6-java.desktop
with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime
Comment=OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime
Exec=cautious-launcher %f /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-6
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```

You should change the "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java" part of Exec to the location of java on your system. Then reboot and the option should be there.

Comment: It suddenly came back on its own when 12.04 came out.

Answer (score 0):

14.04 LTS user here.  Got OpenJDK working from desktop with:

contents of /usr/share/applications/openjdk-7-java.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Comment=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Exec=cautious-launcher %f /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar 
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-7
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```