# lost right-click open with java 7 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: openjdk

Does the following method seem proper enough (or alternatively, fundamentally flawed) as the way to get back the right-click ability for opening with Java?

After some sort of hang and crash of Minecraft, a desktop icon I had configured to open with a double-click no longer worked.  Right-clicking only showed "open with archive manager" and  "open with archive mounter" as options.

From software center, I removed, then re-added Java. That didn't help.

"allow to run as executable" is selected in properties

I followed the instructions in [114990](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114990/lost-right-click-open-with-java-jar-file) but changed Java 6's to Java 7's and launcher to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java (the latter b/c that seemed to be correct after poking around with cd and ls).  So  I now have this:

```
cat "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime"
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Comment=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Exec=cautious-launcher %f /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-7
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```

I rebooted but still nothing came up for right-click or other other places to set "open-with" .

[224463](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224463/how-do-i-reenable-opening-jar-files-by-double-clicking-on-them) does NOT say what to do if the  openjdk-7-java..desktop file does NOT exist and so leaves those of us without it sort of hanging.

So I gambled and renamed "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" (from 114990) to "openjdk-7-java.desktop" (from 224463) and rebooted and magically my Desktop Minecraft icon was already back to being set to "Open with OpenJDK 7 Runtime"

So I'm happy enough for now until I learn otherwise, but I'm curious if this seems proper enough.

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1448548

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me with 14.04 LTS

Contents of /usr/share/applications/openjdk-7-java.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Comment=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
Exec=cautious-launcher %f /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar 
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-7
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```